# Error on installing wheel for pandas which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, pandas, installation, pip, python-wheel

I tried to install pandas from a requirements.txt on my laptop using pip

Window 10
Python 3.11
pip 23.2.1

I tried to install pandas using pip install pandas

```
C:\Users\ABC>pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\abc\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (2.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in c:\users\abc\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\abc\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from pandas) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.1 in c:\users\abc\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from pandas) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.0 in c:\users\abc\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from pandas) (1.25.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\abc\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->pandas) (1.16.0)
```

Seems like all are satisfied.

But here's what happened when I tried to pip the requirements.txt

```
Downloading threadpoolctl-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pandas
  Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pandas (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1565 lines of output]
      <string>:44: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
```

.
.

```
 error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pandas
Failed to build pandas
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pandas, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I already tried to download python 3.10, manually download panda's wheel (pandas-1.4.3-cp311-cp311-win32.whl), and manually add the path to cl.exe. However nothing's changed.

This is what's inside the requirements.txt:

```
numpy
scipy
scikit-learn
joblib
tabulate
pandas==1.2.0
tqdm
scikit-multilearn
```

What should I do? Thank you in advance

I already tried to download python 3.10, manually download panda's wheel (pandas-1.4.3-cp311-cp311-win32.whl), manually add the path to cl.exe, and using GPT to solve it. However nothing's changed.

Comment: Did you leave something out? A warning isn't error. The error is in the cl.exe line, but we'd need the lines before that to see what may be causing that.

Answer (score -1):

The version requirement for Pandas in `requirements.txt` seems awfully stringent. In particular because the other packages have no version requirements *at all*; that's just bad practice, in my opinion.

If you can, alter the `requirements.txt` file to be the following

```
numpy
scipy
scikit-learn
joblib
tabulate
pandas~=1.2.0
tqdm
scikit-multilearn
```

Note that the only change is `==` to `~=`, which means "compatible release".

Then try again. If all works out, pip will install Pandas 1.5.3 (the latest 1-series release), which has a binary wheel for the combination of Windows 10 and Python 3.11; that should make it straightforward to install. Given that 1.2.0 and 1.5.3 are both 1-series, 1.5.3 is very likely compatible for your project (instead of 1.2.0).